# cast priorityQueue to my customized interface

Tags: java

```
public class testCast {

    public interface dataQueue extends Queue<Object>{};

    public static void main (String test[]){        
        dataQueue queue = (dataQueue) new java.util.PriorityQueue<Object>();
        queue.add("Test");
        System.out.println(queue.peek());
    }
}
```

I am wondering why this would cause a casting error....
it would work if I do

`Queue queue = (Queue) new java.util.PriorityQueue<Object>();`
Does anyone know why??
Thanks in advance

Comment: Java does not support [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put simply, because a `PriorityQueue` is a `Queue`, but not a `DataQueue`. The actual class definition matters in Java: just because two interfaces are identical doesn't mean you can cast any implementation of one to the other.

- `DataQueue` is an interface that extends the `Queue` interface.
- `PriorityQueue` is a class that implements the `Queue` interface.

  - It **does not** implement the `DataQueue` interface.
- Therefore, a `PriorityQueue` cannot be cast to `DataQueue`.

---

The hierarchy might make it clearer: just because they have a common ancestor doesn't mean you can cast one to the other.

```
            Queue
      ________|________
     |                 |
 DataQueue       PriorityQueue
```

---

To be even more pedantic about it, let's ramp up the clarity, since the relationship between `Queue` and `DataQueue` is different from the relationship between `Queue` and `PriorityQueue`. The following MSPaint diagram uses **solid lines for inheritance**, and **dashed lines for interface-implementation**.

[image: DataQueue inherits; PriorityQueue implements.]

So, you can't get from a `PriorityQueue` directly to a `DataQueue`. If you did *really* want to be able to make a `PriorityQueue` and call it a `DataQueue` for some reason, this is what you could do: *extend* `PriorityQueue` with a new class, and *implement* your `DataQueue` interface.

```
public class MyQueue extends PriorityQueue<Object> implements DataQueue {
    // Anything you want goes here, or just leave it empty if you only want the default constructor.
}
```

[image: MyQueue inherits from PriorityQueue, and implements DataQueue]

Then you can write `DataQueue q = new MyQueue();` to your heart's content.

---

Finally, note that this *wouldn't work* if you tried to *inherit* from two different classes. Java does not support multiple inheritance. This hierarchy is only possible because `DataQueue` is an interface, rather than a class.

Comment: You can do this simply by extending `PriorityQueue` while implementing `DataQueue`: `class MyQueue extends PriorityQueue<Object> implements DataQueue {}` Then you just create one like this: `DataQueue q = new MyQueue();` but the more important question you should be asking yourself is, why do you want to do this? There is likely an easier solution than all this complicated type-mashing.